# oci8 + php cgi not working

Tags: php, oracle, cgi, centos, oci8

I have successfully instaled oci8 module following this guide:

http://orfeogpl.info/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Oci8_Php5

oci8 is working through php cli but not through cgi /http

Does anyone knows who could i solve it? Is my OS lacking any php package needed by oci8?

Apache error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

ldd -r shows:

```
    ldd -r /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so:
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbc6c2000)             
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => /usr/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00007f326fc12000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f326f879000)                                   
        libnnz11.so => /usr/oracle/instantclient/libnnz11.so (0x00007f326f4b1000)            
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f326f2ad000)                                 
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f326f028000)                                   
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f326ee0b000)                       
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f326ebf2000)                               
        libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f326e9f0000)                               
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000361d400000)                                     
    undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: OnUpdateBool  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: zend_ini_boolean_displayer_cb (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: OnUpdateString        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_standard_class_def       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: le_index_ptr  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: core_globals  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: executor_globals      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: convert_to_double     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: php_info_print_table_start    (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: zend_fetch_resource   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_list_insert      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_hash_del_key_or_index    (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: zend_unregister_ini_entries   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: ap_php_snprintf       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: display_ini_entries   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: add_assoc_null_ex     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_register_internal_class  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: _object_init_ex       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_hash_destroy     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_hash_find        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: _php_stream_free      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: _ecalloc      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: _php_stream_open_wrapper_ex   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: add_index_zval        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: _array_init   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: _emalloc      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: php_printf    (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                             
undefined symbol: add_next_index_stringl        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)             
undefined symbol: _php_stream_write     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)                     
undefined symbol: zend_register_string_constant (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _object_and_properties_init   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_wrong_param_count        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_checkuid  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_strndup  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zval_dtor_func       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: convert_to_array      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_hash_add_or_update      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_list_find       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_num_elements        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters_ex      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _efree        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_next_index_long   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_assoc_zval_ex     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_index_null        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_assoc_string_ex   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_check_open_basedir        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_error_docref0     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_register_list_destructors_ex     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _convert_to_string    (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_info_print_table_row      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _estrdup      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_register_resource        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_info_print_table_end      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_next_index_null   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_assoc_long_ex     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_move_forward_ex     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_apply_with_argument (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_next_index_double (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_list_addref     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: php_strtolower        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _estrndup     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_register_ini_entries     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_hash_init       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_get_current_data_ex (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: gc_remove_zval_from_buffer    (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zval_add_ref  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_strtod   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_bailout (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zval_copy_ctor_func  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _safe_emalloc (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: add_property_resource_ex      (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_register_long_constant   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_index_find  (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: zend_hash_apply       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: convert_to_long       (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _zend_hash_index_update_or_next_insert        (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
undefined symbol: _erealloc     (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so)
```

```
cat /etc/php.ini |grep oci  
    extension=oci8.so  


cat /etc/php.d/oci8.ini  
    extension=oci8.so
```

In the `cli (php -a)`, phpinfo(); shows oci8

```
oci8  

    OCI8 Support => enabled
    Version => 1.4.5
    Revision => $Revision: 305257 $
    Active Persistent Connections => 0
    Active Connections => 0
    Oracle Instant Client Version => 11.2
    Temporary Lob support => enabled
    Collections support => enabled

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
    oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
    oci8.events => Off => Off   
    oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
    oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
    oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
    oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
    oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
    oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
```

Through `http/cgi` phpinfo(); shows:

```
Additional .ini files parsed   /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/oci8.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

Comment: does `phpinfo();` via http shows oci8? if not - then check you conf (httpd.conf) for `extension=oci8.so`

Comment: check the apache erorr.log for erorrs

Comment: cat /etc/php.ini |grep oci
    extension=oci8.so  cat /etc/php.d/oci8.ini
extension=oci8.so In the cli, `php -a`, phpinfo(); shows oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
Version => 1.4.5       
....

Comment: what about apache startup errors?

Comment: + when you telling thet _not work_ - eny errors / exceptions or some code?

Comment: Can't you see the linking errors? Currently it's what i'm trying to solve.

Comment: Apache errors? apacheis well configured so no errors are shown.

Comment: show us the apache error log... even if you say "its well configured" it dosen't mean the log is empty:)

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Disabling SElinux did the trick :)

Comment: I was getting similar error with apache server. I had to remove php.conf file from apache conf.d directory (i.e. disabling loading of php as apache module as I need to run php as CGI)

Answer (score 1):

1. Disabling SElinux
2. Installing `php-mbstring` (solve the `undefined symbol` errors)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like SELinux is messing with library loading

ref: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1119593-oracle-error-oracle-10g-fedora-core-3-a.html